# linked list not inserting new values "C language"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, linked-list

*I'm running into an issue where my linked list is not adding the new values I give it.. it's resulting in a segmentation fault but I am lost on how to fix it*

**Current Code**

```
typedef struct node {
  int value;/*data stored in the node  */
  struct node *next;
 /*pointer to the next node*/
} NODE;

void add(NODE **list, int n){//add_to_list in slides
  NODE *new_node;

  new_node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  if (new_node == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error:malloc failed in add_to_front \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  new_node->value = n;
  new_node->next = *list;
  //return new_node;

}
void print_list(NODE *list){
  printf("\n=========\n");
  for (;list;list=list->next){
    printf("%d\t",list->value);
  }
  printf("\n=========\n");
  }

int main()
{
  NODE *first=NULL;
 
  print_list(first);
  add(&first,10);
  add(&first,30);
  add(&first,20);
  add(&first,40);
  add(&first,30);
  print_list(first);

}
```

**Update**

I added in main but now instead of the segmentation fault nothing prints...

```
add(&first, number)
```

The fault happens in the add function, more specifically this line "new_node->next = *list;"

**I tried dereferencing and many other things, to no avail.**

Comment: You have `NODE *first=NULL;` as the first line if your program. So `first` is an empty list. When do you expect this to change? Point out a line in your code that assigns something to `first` or otherwise changes it.

Comment: so the add function is meant to make additions to the list (first)

Comment: What line in the add function?

Comment: its in main add(&first,10) is the first thing it adds

Comment: ohhhhh... i just got it

Comment: If you remove all statements from the `add` function, leaving just empty braces `{}`, it will obviously not add anything. If you add a `printf` to `add`, it will still not add anything. So in order for `add(&first,10)` to add something, it needs to execute a very specific statement that adds something to something.. Which statement you believe is doing that? Show the line number.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing that out... dumb mistake its 4am here and my brains working overtime right now.. thanbkyou

Answer (score 0):

The node is not inserted because you do not update the head pointer: add this statement at the end of the `add()` function:

```
        *list = new_node;
```

Comment: yes yes, thankyou! i was tired and didnt realize i had forgotten to reflect the new chnages in the array!

Answer (score 0):

make the changes to the dereferenced list

```
(*list) = new_node;
```

in order to add the new_node values into the list.